# How can i fix illegal offset type

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm getting an error saying that I have an illegal offset in this code:

```
public function add_result(){


      $marks= $this->input->post('marks');
      print_r($marks);

      $subject= $this->input->post('subject');
      print_r($subject);

       $st_roll= $this->input->post('st_roll');
       print_r($st_roll);

       $marks= array($st_roll => array( $subject => $marks)); 

        foreach($marks as $key => $value){                             
            foreach($value as $sub => $value1)
            {
                echo "{$key} - {$sub} - {$value1} <br>";                              
            }                              
        }

    }
```

(illegal offset warning in this line)

```
$marks= array($st_roll => array( $subject => $marks));
```

Comment: Firs things first... You should at the very least be validating your form inputs. You are printing out $marks, $subject and $st_roll. What are these values? Some example data would be helpful. I.E what you expect the data is and what the actual data is.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function add_result(){


    $marks= "demo10";
    $subject= "markss";
    $st_roll= "rollno15";

    $marks = array($st_roll => array( $subject => $marks)); 

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($marks);
    echo "</pre>";

    foreach($marks as $key => $value)
    {                             
        foreach($value as $sub => $value1)
        {
            echo "{$key} - {$sub} - {$value1} <br>";                              
        }                              
    }

}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAgEC.png